# Dragon Player keeps crashing

Tags: kubuntu, dragon

A Linux newbie here #Straightouttawindows.
I'm using Kubuntu and my "Dragon Player" which comes with Kubuntu itself keeps crashing as soon as I turn on a movie. Please teach me how do I uninstal it and instal a VLC player

Answer (score 1):

to install VLC media player

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

then enter your login password, wait for it install

to uninstall dragon player

```
sudo apt-get remove dragon
```